# Changing access permission on required library in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I'm sure one of you guys have been in a similar situation where a class within a plugin that is part of the required extension is not accessible: `Discouraged access: The type MethodBinding is not accessible due to restriction on required library org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.7.jar`. I physically changed the access rules by going in the build path and I was able to access the desired class.

Here is my question, when I export my plugin and install it on other Eclipse will the access rules that I manually changed keep its configuration or will I have to physically set the access rules on the other Eclipse as well? If it is the latter, is there a way to physically change the rules?

Any idea, thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can configure it via `Preference` - `Java` - `Compile` - `Errors Warning`.

Change `Discourage Reference` to `Warning` or `Ignore`.